# Operations with ip-address

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have some ip-addresses that a user gives:

```
192.168.50.$i
```

now I want to do `+200` with `$i`. So if the user does:

```
bash script 52 20 56
```

The result must be

```
ping 192.168.50.252 , ...
```

I thought to do something like:

```
function
{
  $i = $i + 200
  ping 192.168.50.$i
}
```

And what can I do when it's higher then 255?

Comment: Did you any googleing about "bash + math" for example? What do you want to do if the input is invalid (> 204)?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this...

```
echo "192.168.50.$(( $i + 200 ))"
```

If you wanted to check if it is greater than 255 you will have to break it down a bit.

```
fourth=$(( $i + 200 ))
if (( fourth > 255 ))
then
    echo "Greater than 255!"
    exit 1
fi
```

<strike>**Question change**</strike> *Didn't see last part*

You could create a function but this wont work as the syntax is way out.

```
function
{
    $i = $i + 200
    ping 192.168.50.$i
}
```

You will need to do something like this...

```
# Function name
function ip_assess {

    # $1 takes the first input to the function
    # There is no $ when assigning to a variable
    # There is no spaces around the = when assigning
    i=$(( $1 + 200 ))

    # No need for $ when doing arithmetic comparisons
    if (( i > 255 ))
    then
        # Return an error code of 1 from this function
        return 1
    fi

    # -c 4 will get it to ping four times and return and not continuously
    # If the ping is a success return 0 (a pass). If no then 2 (different error code)
    ping "192.168.50.$i" -c 4 && return 0 || return 2

}

ip_assess 30
# Grab the error code
valid_ip=$?

case $valid_ip in
    0 )
        echo "Valid IP"
    ;;
    1 )
        echo "IP is to high"
    ;;
    2 )
        echo "IP not alive"
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: It doesn't works the way you wrote it. It gives a mistake on i=((...))

Comment: @gladius whoops missed the $ :D

Comment: @gladius And a space on the function! **And didn't grab the error code properly** Wow, not my day! :P

Comment: where do I have to add a space on function?

Comment: It was between the bracket and name at the end `ip_assess{` -> `ip_assess {`